# How do I use a For Loop Statement to create one dataframe of a similar column from 4 data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
assets = ['MSFT', 'FB', 'TWTR', 'UBER']
for asset in assets:
   asset = yf.Ticker(asset).history(start="2017-01-01", end="2020-05-01")
```

From this, I'll get 4 time series data frames in the format below.

```
                 Open   High    Low  Close     Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date
2019-05-10  42.00  45.00  41.06  41.57  186322500          0             0
2019-05-13  38.79  39.24  36.08  37.10   79442400          0             0
2019-05-14  38.31  39.96  36.85  39.96   46661100          0             0
2019-05-15  39.37  41.88  38.95  41.29   36086100          0             0
2019-05-16  41.48  44.06  41.25  43.00   38115500          0             0
```

I am trying to create a time series dataframe with just the 'Close' values for 4 different stocks. Just like below:

```
            MSFT_Close   FB_Close    TWTR_Close  UBER_Close
Date
2019-05-10    42.00        45.00       41.06       41.57
2019-05-13    38.79        39.24       36.08       37.10 
2019-05-14    38.31        39.96       36.85       39.96 
2019-05-15    39.37        41.88       38.95       41.29 
2019-05-16    41.48        44.06       41.25       43.00
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension for dict of `Series`:

```
d = {asset: yf.Ticker(asset).history(start="2017-01-01", end="2020-05-01")['Close'] 
                                                                    for asset in assets}
```

Or loop alternative:

```
d = {}
for asset in assets:
     d[asset] = yf.Ticker(asset).history(start="2017-01-01", end="2020-05-01")
```

And then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1, keys=assets).add_suffix('_Close')
```